# Looking for stop watch alarm clock app similiar to one on iphone on OSX for macbookpro

Tags: macos, productivity

Can I install an app on my MacBook pro similar to the the stop-watch/alarm-clock app on iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something similar to the app **[Awaken](http://embraceware.com/awaken/mac/en/)**. It has a similar look, clock, alarms (with sounds, music via iTunes and even executing scripts or apps) and timer with sleep mode (needs the Awaken Helper, provided at its website as well). Many of us are waiting for a future version including also a stopwatch.